# C# Asp.net Json CustomConverter error when converting from string to object, when invoked from API call

Tags: c#, json, exception, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I use C# ASP.NET Net6 to create a webapi. There I use a custom jsonconverter to convert a custom class which is called Password. The string comes from the body of a request dto. During converting from string to object I check with a regex if the password meets requirements and throw an exception in case of failure. This causes my application to break.

- What is the proper way to check the string, which is to be parsed, before converting to an object?
- Do I need to throw a special exception?
- Can I somehow check the value in CanConvert before Read Function?

```cs
namespace TestApp.Converters
{
    public class PasswordJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Password>
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
        {
            return typeToConvert == typeof(Password);
        }

        public override Password? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if(!Password.TryParse(reader.GetString(), out Password pw))
            {
                throw new JsonException("test"); // <= this causes the application to stop
            }

            return pw;
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Password value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use annotations to perform validations on data models. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Hi, yes I've seen this possibility, thx. 
My thought was: When I reuse the same check in different routes (and I wanna change something) I need to change the annotations in all of the DTO's where I use it in.
Whereas, when I do it like this I only need to change the validation rules in one place. That I use Password class is just an example for a wider variety of possible Properties.

Comment: You can write your own custom validation and annotate your class with them and change it when you have change in validation logic

Comment: if you don't want annotations then you can think of using FluentValidation.